# Android appwidget start new activity

Tags: android, android-widget

I created appwidget(StackView widget)and I can show images and text in StackView widget. Now i want if I click StackView widget should start new activity, for example, MainActivity.java. I wrote code which can to show toast message in widget position but I do not know how to start new activity instead of toast message. This is a my code

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.example.android.stackwidget.TOAST_ACTION";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.example.android.stackwidget.EXTRA_ITEM";
private RemoteViews views;
private Intent intent;

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Touched view " + viewIndex,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        intent = new Intent(context, MyRemoteViewsService.class);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.stackWidgetView, intent);

        views.setEmptyView(R.id.stackWidgetView, R.id.stackWidgetEmptyView);

        Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context,
                BriGeWidgetProvider.class);
        templateIntent.setAction(BriGeWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, templateIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stackWidgetView,
                templatePendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

}

```
public class MyRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    return new BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}

class BriGeRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    private ArrayList<ItemI> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public BriGeRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        itemList = getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        itemList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (itemList != null)
            return itemList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        ItemI item = itemList.get(position);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.item_view);

        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.title, item.getTitle());
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.img, getImageBitmap(item.getImage()));
        // rv.setTextViewText(R.id.descr, item.getDescription());

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(BriGeWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
        Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtras(extras);

        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.title, fillIntent);
        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.img, fillIntent);
        // rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.descr, fillIntent);

        return rv;
    }

    private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    private ArrayList<ItemI> getData() {
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(context);
        return jp.getDataAsList();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use PendinIndent to go from MyWidgetProvider  to  MyRemoteViewsService.class.

Do it in "onUpdate" method-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyRemoteViewsService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
RemoteViews remoteViews = remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button , pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Use `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityClassName.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));`

Comment: i tryed but i have error this is a my LogCat error: java.lang.runtimeException: Unable to  start MyWidgetProvider : Calling new Activity from outside of an Activity

Comment: edited my answer with a workaround, which may not be always best fit, but works

Answer (score 0):

You should set an on click pending intent to your remote view.

See this- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent

And this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012520/713778

Comment: yes i know i used Intent to call MyRemoteViewsService class in Opdate method but now i want  to call activity in widget click for example Mainactivity.java class

Comment: I do not see a in your code, where you set on click pending intent on your remote view. This pending intent will be fired every time user clicks on your widget.

Comment: Did you have a lookt at this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Answer (score 0):

On Button Press:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent("PACKAGENAME.CLASSNAME");
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Or:

```
newIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("PACKAGENAME", "PACKAGENAME.CLASSNAME"));
                newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newIntent);
```